# ScrollReveal with webpack - ReferenceError: ScrollReveal is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, referenceerror, laravel-mix, scrollreveal.js

Using **Laravel 5.6.29** with **laravel-mix@2.1.11** & **webpack@3.12.0**.

After installing **scrollreveal@3.4.0** via `npm i scrollreveal` and requiring it in my **app.js** with `require('scrollreveal')`, I see that in my **app.js** output that **ScrollReveal** is there to be found.

However, when I try to initiate it with `window.sr = ScrollReveal();` it throws me an error: **ReferenceError: ScrollReveal is not defined**, even though the reference comes after the definition.

I tried it with two different ways. First is to:

**resources/assets/js/app.js**

```
require('scrollreveal');
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
```

or the second way which is:

**resources/views/index.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
</script>
```

However, if I just include the js the traditional way:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
```

and then make a call to ScrollReveal(), it actually works.

Perhaps it's somehow a scope problem? But why would it only appear with ScrollReveal and not any other libraries I use? And isn't NodeJS **require()** function importing to global scope?

**UPDATE:** Third way I found that fixes this problem is by changing **resources/assets/js/app.js** and adding:

```
import ScrollReveal from 'scrollreveal';
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
```

will fix the issue, as this will in-scope define **window.sr** as **ScrollReveal()** using ES6 import (appearantly).

However, why wouldn't NodeJS require work still?

Comment: Using your Update fix, worked for me as well. I am worried about the comment in the official docs, that the library must be added before the closing of <head>, although I think this is a problem for people that want to animate on initial view port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work, in a way I don't yet know why it works (do elaborate if you know!), but it works.

Changing **resources/assets/js/app.js** and adding:

```
require('scrollreveal')().reveal('.sreveal');
```

fixes the issue, using the NodeJS require().